# How do I select MySQL destination table in SQL Server Import and Export Wizard?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

I have successfully transferred some data from a remote *`MySQL`* database into our local *`SQL Server`* database.

I am now trying to send some data back to *MySQL* and hitting some issues. I'm using the **`SQL Server Import and Export Wizard`**. When I specify a query to send the data back to *MySQL* I get as far as the mapping stage and it will only let me create a new table called *`Query`* to pass the data to.

I cannot select an existing table from my *MySQL* database , it just shows *`Query`* or blank.

Does anyone know why the tables are not being displayed? I believe possible to do this basic task and populate or update an existing table.

I have previously used **`SqlYog`** for transferring data from *SQL Server* to *MySQL* but it only works one way.

I would like a solution for sending and retrieving data between *MySQL* and *SQL Server*.

Any help is appreciated, and if you know of any other tools I may benefit from please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Import and Export Wizard generates (and optionally runs) an SSIS package.  If the wizard breaks I would build the SSIS package manually, using BIDS (Visual Studio).

Then (depending on the drivers you are using) you probably need either an OLE DB Destination or an ADO NET Destination within your Data Flow to deliver the data.